# Xcode Static Analyser for Nullpointer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, static-analysis

Is there any static analyser tool for Xcode which can detect intentional null object access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. Go to Product->Analyze. This will run an analysis through your code and gives you the information required.

[image]

Please let me know if you're looking for something else so that I can edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I am wodering if xcodes default analyzer can detect nil object access on build time.